# CAMetalLayer nextDrawable returning nil because allocation failed

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard, runtime-error, metal

I'm new to Swift and Mac development and I'm trying to make a framework (only macOS) that can open a Metal window. I use Xcode Version 11.3.1 on macOS version 10.15.2.

I started from the examples that I found on the web (macOS/Command Line Tool project to start) and I do not see how to correct this error:

> [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because allocation failed.

When the project is created with a storyboard (macOS/App project) the window opens with the expected content (filling in red) but when I try to replace the storyboard with code (macOS/Command Line Tool project) the execution loops on the error mentioned above .
    Main.swift

```
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow!
    var viewController: ViewController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSLog("Start app")

        viewController = ViewController()
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1024, 768),
                          styleMask: .borderless,
                          backing: .buffered,
                          defer: false)

        window.contentViewController = viewController
        window.title = "Hey, new Window!"
        window.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue
        window.orderFrontRegardless()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSLog("Terminate app")
    }

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

let app = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = appDelegate

app.run()
```

ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa
import Metal
import MetalKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var mtkView: MTKView!
    var renderer: Renderer!

    override func loadView() {
        mtkView = MTKView()
        self.view = mtkView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let defaultDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
            print("Metal is not supported on this device")
            return
        }

        print("My GPU is: \(defaultDevice)")
        mtkView.device = defaultDevice

        guard let tempRenderer = Renderer(mtkView: mtkView) else {
            print("Renderer failed to initialize")
            return
        }
        renderer = tempRenderer

        mtkView.delegate = renderer
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Renderer.swift

```
import Foundation
import Metal
import MetalKit

class Renderer : NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

    let device: MTLDevice
    let commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue

    init?(mtkView: MTKView) {
        device = mtkView.device!
        commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
    }

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { return }

        guard let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }

        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 0, 0, 1)

        guard let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { return }

        renderEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)

        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

    }
}
```

In my research I found only one post that could help me that was using `NSViewControllerRepresentable` but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: I definitely would not try to Frankenstein-meld a command line tool with a lifecycle app.

Comment: I agree with matt. The `MTKView` most likely need to be part of a window/view hierarchy to be able to allocate buffers properly.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, it is not possible to define entries in a framework that allow you to open a Metal window and control its content?

Comment: What you're showing us is _not_ a framework. It's a command-line tool. It has a _Main.swift_. You're saying `app.run`. None of that would happen in a framework.

Comment: If the answer you received solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most immediate issue here is that your `CAMetalLayer`, the layer that backs your `MTKView`, has size (0, 0). Therefore the layer can't allocate drawables for you to draw into.

The reason your layer has zero size is because your `MTKView` has zero size, and the reason your view has zero size is because you create it without specifying a frame. Per the documentation, "Setting `contentViewController` causes the window to resize based on the current size of the `contentViewController`;" hence your window is also zero sized.

Provide a size when creating your `MTKView` and things will "work":

```
mtkView = MTKView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
```

Echoing comments above, I recommend against this approach, since `NSApplication`'s `run()` method doesn't do everything necessary to make the app a good macOS citizen. The app won't have a Dock tile, it won't have a main menu, and you won't be able to use common keyboard shortcuts like Cmd+Q without added effort. If you're designing a framework to make it easier for people to create windows with minimal effort, this is too minimal. Nor is it possible or supported to implement everything that `NSApplicationMain` does on your behalf with public API. Encourage users of your framework to follow platform design patterns rather than trying to wrest control away from them in the name of simplicity. If they're already running a full-fledged app with a proper run loop, you can create windows on their behalf without needing to touch the `NSApplication` stratum.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is absolutely pointing to the real problem here, so please, all kudos to him. But in my case, there was another obstacle, which is the Auto-Layout call cycle.

## Programmatic Auto Layout

So, if you're working on a project that has a programmatic approach to managed Auto Layout then you've to create your view just after that. In my case, I was also adding the Metal view as another child View Controller. So in my case solution was, basically calling inside the correct life cycle method.

I've just moved my method call (adding child View Controller) in the  **viewDidLayoutSubviews()** method.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    add(self.cameraVC, frame: container.frame)
}
```

I hope, this will help cases like mine.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it can also happen when the `MTKView` is asked to `draw` while not yet inserted in a view hierarchy.
For example, if the Metal view is created, fed with camera input, but then the view is added to a superview only later on.